# js get nodes in a structured dictionary

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree, nodes

I want to get all nodes of a particular parent element in a structured dictionary. for example, with following HTML:

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <h1>
        <a href="#"></a>
        <p></p>
    </h1>
    <span></span>
    <form>
        <div>
            <h2></h2>
            <label>
                <input type="text">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button></button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

The expected output is:

```js
{
    "div": [
        {"h1": [
            "a",
            "p",
        ]},
        "span",
        {"form": [
            {"div": [
                "h2",
                {"label": ["input"]},
            ]},
            {"div": ["button"]},
        ]},
        "span",
    ],
}
```

any advice will be appreciated.

---

#### Update

This function to manipulate parent and child;

```js
// func takes a parent and a child as param
function recursor(parent, node, func){
    if(node.children.length){
        for(let ii = 0; ii < node.children.length; ii++){
            recursor(node, node.children[ii], func);
        }
    }else{
        func(parent, node);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please may you share what you have already tried as a [mcve]? This so that we can help you with where you might have gone wrong, rather than giving you opinionated advice about starting from scratch.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I wonder if there is an accessible attribute that I can directly use instead of coding my own recursion function.

Comment: After selecting the root element, every node has a `children` property. You can use that. AFAIK there is no "make JS object tree" utility built in.

Comment: Is the HTML input a string? Or is that part of the web page that your JavaScript is running on?

Comment: it's html, not a string

Comment: OK, I suppose you mean it's running in a web page. HTML is always text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive function, translating the DOM structure (of which it is a simplification) to your target structure:

```js
const getTree = root => root.children.length 
        ? {
              [root.tagName.toLowerCase()]: Array.from(root.children, getTree)
          } 
        : root.tagName.toLowerCase();

const result = getTree(document.getElementById("wrapper"));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <h1>
        <a href="#"></a>
        <p></p>
    </h1>
    <span></span>
    <form>
        <div>
            <h2></h2>
            <label>
                <input type="text">
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button></button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: this is ELEGANT, much better than mine